# How to return a value from an R function with Control Structure

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to extract the rating from a column inside a DataFrame. I have written the below function. However, the function would not stop executing and the column does not get updated.

**Column values** are string for example;

- Rating R violence sexual content language
- Rating PG-13 content language
- ""

Desired output:

- if the row value of the column is **""** or empty than the new value should be **NA**
- if the row value of the column is Rating R violence sexual content language, than the new value should be **"R"**
- if the row value of the column is Rating PG-13 content language, than the new value should be **"PG-13"**

  ```
  C <- function (column) 
  {
    len <- length(DF$column)

    for (i in 1:len) 

    {
      a <- DF$column[i]
      b <-  unlist(strsplit(a," "))

    if ( length(b) == 0 ) 
    {

      x <-  NA

      DF$column[i] <- x

     } else ( b[1] == "Rating" & length(b) > 0 ) 

     DF$column[i] <- mpaaRating[2]


    } 
  }  


  DF$mpaa <- CleanMpaa(DF$mpaa)
  ```

Thank you

Comment: *otherwise what ever follows the Rating i.e. R.*...what does this mean? It might help to illustrate with example data.

Comment: Hi parfait, I have clarified my question. I hope this helps. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a nested `ifelse`. No loop is needed:

```
DF <- data.frame(list(mpaa=c("Rating R", "Rating PG-13", "", "PG")), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DF
#           mpaa
# 1     Rating R
# 2 Rating PG-13
# 3              
# 4           PG

DF$clean_mpaa <- ifelse(nchar(DF$mpaa) == 0, NA, 
                        ifelse(grepl("Rating", DF$mpaa),          # FINDS PATTERN
                               gsub("Rating ", "", DF$mpaa),      # REPLACES PATTERN
                               DF$mpaa))
#           mpaa clean_mpaa
# 1     Rating R          R
# 2 Rating PG-13      PG-13
# 3                    <NA>
# 4           PG         PG
```

Comment: Hi Parfait. the DF should include the full string, e.g. Rating R violence sexual content language. After applying the if else, the new value should be "R" or PG etc. Thank you.

Comment: I do not understand. This solution adds a new field which strips out *"Rating"*, so you retain original as well as new column. You may need to post desired results and actual data.